# hidden view blocking (and not responding to) gestureRecognizer

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, hidden

I'm trying to dismiss a `UITextField` using a `UITapGestureRecognizer` connected to the background image of the view.

```
 @IBAction func dismissKeyboard(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) 
       {self.view.endEditing(true)}
```

When tapping in most places on the background it dismisses just fine, but the problem is, I have a hidden `UILabel` (which displays a small red "item already added!" on the side if the text in the box matches a previous instance) that seems to get in the way of tapping part of the `UIImageView`. Adding the Label to the "`Referencing Outlet Collections`" doesn't help either, because the Label is hidden. I've tested when the label is unhidden and it works fine... Understandably when hidden, the Label doesn't respond to taps, but why does it block the taps of the image beneath it? Any way to make the Label "tapically" hidden as well.

I could make alpha = 0 instead of using hidden, but the method I'm currently using is much more efficient and I can't imagine changing would be the only way to work around this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: label.userInteractionDisabled = YES ?

Comment: @LordZsolt nope, that's not the problem. I can interact w/ the label (as proved by the fact that the keyboard dismisses when I tap it while it's not hidden). The problem is only when it's hidden. Even enabling user interaction AFTER setting the label to hidden doesn't help. I just don't understand how there can't be a way to make it stop blocking my taps while hidden, or at least accept taps itself

Comment: Shouldn't you disable the user interaction?